Trouble with pgfplots' axis and beamer overlay
I want to plot a function and draw some points whose definition and coordinates depend on a variable, whose value should change slide by slide in beamer, and some elements appear/disappear in phases. In essence, I'm trying to have a drawing parametrized by the slide number, where the parametrization is not a simple constant expression. I know I want to use axis from pgfplots as the style is neat for plotting functions, but it seems rather problematic with beamer.
Let me give a concrete example that hopefully minimally represents what I am trying to achieve. Say I want to plot the function f: x in [0,1] -> min(1,a*x^2) where a will go from 1 to 2. Specifically, slide by slide:

Plot the graph of f at a=1.
Add to that the convex hull of its graph, still at a=1.
Add a thick line highlighting its intersection with the vertical line x=1/2
Highlight the lowest point of that line (with a small filled circle).
Add a dashed curve that denotes the lower part of this region (which, in this case, coincides with the graph of f itself). Only leave the function, the dashed curve and the highlighted point.
From now increase a until a=2 in how ever many slides. The function, the dashed curve and the point should be highlighted. Moreover, if the curve is flat at the point (which it will be as soon as a>4/3), I also want to highlight the two ends of that flat line.

This can be done explicitly by hand, working out what the convex hull is and the tangency point. The code below does just that, but I would like the "movie" part to be a foreach loop instead of having to write everything by hand if possible.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    % Phase 1: set up
    \addplot[name path=f, domain=0:1, visible on=<1-5>] {x^2};
    \path[name path=up] (0,0) -- (1,1);
    \addplot[thick, blue, opacity=0.05, visible on=<2-4>] fill between[of=up and f, soft clip={domain=0:1}];
    \draw[dashed, visible on=<3-10>] (1/2,0) -- (1/2,1);
    \draw[very thick, red!50, visible on=<3-4>] (1/2,1/4) -- (1/2,1/2);
    \fill[red, visible on=<4-5>] (1/2,1/4) circle (2pt);
    \addplot[very thick, dashed, red, visible on=<5>, domain=0:1] {x^2}; 
    
    % Phase 2: the movie
    % How to have \only<n>{...} written just once, instead of five times here, wrapped in a \foreach loop?
    \only<6>{
        \def\a{1.2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xa}{1-sqrt(1-1/\a)}%
        \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100] {min(1,\a*x^2)};
        \addplot[very thick, dashed, red, domain=0:1, samples=100] {x<\xa ? \a*x^2 : \a*\xa*(2*x-\xa)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yhalf}{1/2<\xa ? \a/4 : \a*\xa*(1-\xa)}
        \fill[red] (1/2,\yhalf) circle (2pt);}
    
    \only<7>{
        \def\a{1.4}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xa}{1-sqrt(1-1/\a)}%
        \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100] {min(1,\a*x^2)};
        \addplot[very thick, dashed, red, domain=0:1, samples=100] {x<\xa ? \a*x^2 : \a*\xa*(2*x-\xa)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yhalf}{1/2<\xa ? \a/4 : \a*\xa*(1-\xa)}%
        \fill[red] (1/2,\yhalf) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (\xa,\a*\xa*\xa) circle (2pt);}
    
    \only<8>{
        \def\a{1.6}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xa}{1-sqrt(1-1/\a)}%
        \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100] {min(1,\a*x^2)};
        \addplot[very thick, dashed, red, domain=0:1, samples=100] {x<\xa ? \a*x^2 : \a*\xa*(2*x-\xa)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yhalf}{1/2<\xa ? \a/4 : \a*\xa*(1-\xa)}%
        \fill[red] (1/2,\yhalf) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (\xa,\a*\xa*\xa) circle (2pt);}
    
    \only<9>{
        \def\a{1.8}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xa}{1-sqrt(1-1/\a)}%
        \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100] {min(1,\a*x^2)};
        \addplot[very thick, dashed, red, domain=0:1, samples=100] {x<\xa ? \a*x^2 : \a*\xa*(2*x-\xa)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yhalf}{1/2<\xa ? \a/4 : \a*\xa*(1-\xa)}%
        \fill[red] (1/2,\yhalf) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (\xa,\a*\xa*\xa) circle (2pt);}
    
    \only<10>{
        \def\a{2}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\xa}{1-sqrt(1-1/\a)}%
        \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=100] {min(1,\a*x^2)};
        \addplot[very thick, dashed, red, domain=0:1, samples=100] {x<\xa ? \a*x^2 : \a*\xa*(2*x-\xa)};
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\yhalf}{1/2<\xa ? \a/4 : \a*\xa*(1-\xa)}%
        \fill[red] (1/2,\yhalf) circle (2pt);
        \fill[red] (\xa,\a*\xa*\xa) circle (2pt);}
    
    \fill[red, visible on=<7->] (1,1) circle (2pt);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


Just a thought: Have you considered using a foreach around the frame,  instead of inside it. This would enable you to make a series of beamer frames, which are varied by a parameter. (sort of like an animation)

No, actually I never even thought you could do that. Do you wrap a whole frame inside a tikzpicture and then inside a foreach? I'm not sure I follow.

foreach doesn't need to be used inside a tikzpicture, you can use it on  anything (even around a tikzpicture)

Do you intend for the point to follow a parametric curve as you iterate through slides? Another question: do you intend to make this into something like a .gif?

Whaaaat :o I thought it was a TikZ-only command, and that it could only work inside a tikzpicture. I am reading the documentation, it looks like foreach belongs to the package pgffor. That is wild.

Haha, I had a similar reaction when I found this out

Well, the point will be on a curve, but I have its precise coordinates defined.

Those coordinates change with respect to the slide number though, right?

I tried placing the foreach outside the frame as you indicated, the behavior is different but still unexpected. Now it produces three slides and show the point on slides 1 and 3. If I iterate over {1,2,...,n} it actually produces a slide with the point then 1 slide without, then a slide with the point, then 2 slides without, ..., then a slide with the point, then n-1 slides without, and finally a slide with the point.

Yes, it's something like sqrt(i+i^2)/(1+i) (that's just a simpler dummy expression, but I only use squaring, arithmetics and a square-root).

beamer slides count from 0 ;) you can fix this using \pgfmathparse{int(\i-1)}

I can be more precise: the slide number is just there to animate. I actually have something like \foreach \myvalue [count=\i] in {v1, v2, v3, v4} {\draw[visible on=<\i>] ({sqrt(\myvalue+\myvalue^2)/(1+\myvalue)},0) circle (2pt);}

Independently of what I am trying to do, however, why do we observe the above behavior with 16 slides produced?

Does this help? By the way, if your goal is to animate these, I wrote a program which does this: https://github.com/Pseudonym321/LaTeX_Repository/blob/main/TikZ/codes/Animation_Modules/animatetex.py
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,0.05,...,1} {
\begin{frame}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
    \addplot[domain=0:1] {sqrt(x+x^2)/(1+x)};
    \fill (\i, {sqrt(\i+\i^2)/(1+\i)}) circle[radius=2pt];
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
}
\end{document}


I think it does. I'll have to iron out the details for my own problem, but this seems like the solution, thanks! I'll look into it a little later, but compiling what you sent was very promising.

@Cryme I want to mention that beamer is the best for making "portable" animations. Also, 24 frames is a good amount. (using beamer with 24 slides enables you to insert it in TeX.SE as a gif which fits the screen, and isn't too large to load)

True, but I'm looking to change the slides myself (to be animated by hand basically). I recall there are some fancy things one can do, but I want my document to remain a plain pdf (without animated gifs or embedded medias), which is why I try to keep everything into one beamer.

There is one issue though, this method creates multiple slides in the counter. Do you know how to circumvent this?

@Cryme Ahh, I didn't realize you wanted to do it manually. I only know a little bit about beamer, but I think I see what  you want. You want a frame that has some stuff that shows up after you click, without each successive iteration of this "quasi-animation" being a new frame in itself. Let me see if I can adjust the answer.

@Cryme It is likely that this is out of my depth, so if you want, you could rephrase the question and remove the checkmark for my answer, or ask a new question. I will still try, but I am more of a gif/embedded media animator ;)

Yes, sorry if that wasn't all too clear. Basically I will animate a figure manually, with different stages and have some elements appear only on some slides such as circling nodes containing comments, etc. I thought it'd be best to describe the problem in simple terms.

It might help if you created a mock-up of a few slides like this (with counters), and then asked how to remove the counters?

You mean as another question? I feel that this solution would be amazing to animate using a constant expression, but might not be best suited for multiple different phases as I'm looking to animate. I'm trying to edit my question to give an explicit minimal example which if it were solved would solve my problem. I'm stuck at trying to type math mode LaTeX in the question. Neither $$ $$ nor $ $ nor [ ] seem to work. I can't recall how to type math here, do you know how to do that?

@Cryme Ah I think I see what you are getting at, you want to "quasi-animate" several things in a row, as several frames contained in one slide. By the way, I don't think you can add math to a question on TeX.SE. A photo of the math, or just its latex (as people here are fluent) should be fine.

I see, what a bummer, I guess I was thinking of math.stackexchange which has the same frontend. No problem, I'm making the math simple enough to be read as text.

I have edited my question, it now contains an explicit example, worked out entirely without \foreach. The goal is to do the same with a \foreach instead of having to copy-paste and edit each version. I'll keep the question unsolved as you said, so that other people can see the question as well.

@Cryme Good edit! I think that a single foreach cannot do it alone, but maybe a start frame, and a couple consecutive foreaches could accomplish this. The key with foreach is to parameterize the differences you are trying to make. By the way, you should unaccept this answer to motivate more people to answer/let them know the topic is still open.

I mean, it should be doable in one \foreach, just for the "movie" part which is defined through a single expression (save for a condition to decide to draw or not the two end points, but I hope this can be done painlessly using \if...\fi, or at worst I could make two \foreach loops).

@Cryme Ah yes, with conditionals, a single foreach should suffice. Good catch

Right, but then it just miserably fails if you do the obvious: \foreach \a [count=\i from 6] in {1.2,...,2} {\only<\i>{...}}.

@Cryme I don't know beamer syntax well enough to use \only<>. I think you've asked a good question though, and that someone with more expertise should be able to assist.

Glad you're recognizing it as such! Don't hesitate to edit my question if you find how to word it better.
